# PHP MySQL importing uploaded csv errors

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, pdo

I am extremely new to php/mysql but got stuck creating a page that allows my user to upload a csv file and replace changed data/insert new data. I know my DB connection works as I have another page to display the DB contents in a sortable/searchable manner. Below is the code and errors I get.

dataimport.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="dataimport.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

dataimport.php

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  exit();
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }

$datafile = $_FILES["file"];

  try
{
  $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE'".$datafile."' REPLACE INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@col1,@col2,@col3...)";
  $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
  include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
  exit();
}
?>
```

Output I get:

```
Upload: Report.csv
Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Size: 1010.1943359375 kB
Stored in: E:\XAMPP\tmp\phpBD04.tmp
Notice: Array to string conversion in \dataimport.php on line 21

Unable to connect to the database server.
exception 'PDOException' with message       'SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in \dataimport.php:24 Stack trace: #0 \dataimport.php(24): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
```

I know I'm probably including the file wrong in the $sql line but for the life of me I'm beating my head on a wall here and cannot find an example that will help.

Adding db include

```
<?php
try
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
  include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/error.html.php';
  exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: It is saying that `Unable to connect to the database server.` therefore it means that your login credentials are not correct. You should have a configuration file where you should put `host`, `user`, `password` and `database`

Comment: As stated in the initial post, the db included file is valid and working, I use the exact same include on another page so I know user/pass/etc is correct. Code specifically states the unable to connect error, that is not a system generated error.

Comment: Where do you initialize the `$pdo` object through which you are trying to query the database?

Comment: added db include file. As stated before the user/pass/etc are all verified working through another page.

Comment: As a clarification, I have verified the error is kicked by dataimport.php not the db include

Comment: Which is the 24th line?

Comment: 24th line is  $s->execute();

Answer (score 2):

```
'Access denied for user 'nocreport'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

You have wrong db connection configuration. username or password doesn't match.

Edit.

Did some research after you added more source code.

1. Check if you have `FILE` permission granted for user `'nocreport'@'localhost'`.
2. You can also try to add `LOCAL` keyword like this:

   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$datafile."' REPLACE INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@col1,@col2,@col3...)

Comment: As stated in the initial post, the db included file is valid and working, I use the exact same include on another page so I know user/pass/etc is correct. Code specifically states the unable to connect error, that is not a system generated error

Comment: PDO returns here error given by RDBMS system. Do you maybe use multiple db connections? Actually we can't see the way you initialize your PDO object, so we can't tell you more.

Comment: I can only guess, but maybe you don't have credentials for this user to do "LOAD DATA" operation.

Comment: Edited answer adding some advices for you that may help.